# Global Countdown that waits to Start Till All Players Out of Menu

Tags: roblox

I have a game I'm working on and have just implemented a 5 minute countdown for the rounds which works but it starts as soon as the server is made even if all players are still in the menu. The code below works as said before works but I don't know how to make it wait until all the players have left the menu. I want it to wait until a script located `game.Workspace.Blank_Teller` is disbaled for all users. (It disabled once the player has left the menu) I'm new to scripting so sorry if I explained it bad.

```
local rep = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local minutesvalue = rep:WaitForChild("Minutes")
local secondsvalue = rep:WaitForChild("Seconds")
local minutes = 5 --minutes
local seconds = 0 --seconds

while true do
    minutesvalue.Value = minutes
    secondsvalue.Value = seconds

    repeat
        if secondsvalue.Value <= 0 then
            minutesvalue.Value = minutesvalue.Value - 1
            secondsvalue.Value = 59
        else
            secondsvalue.Value = secondsvalue.Value - 1
        end
        wait(1)
    until secondsvalue.Value <= 0 and minutesvalue.Value <= 0
end
```

I've tried to make a player send a number of +1 to the script then once it equals 6 (max player count) it would start the timer but as said before, I'm new and it just didn't work at all.